# Extract list from all_simple_paths and their lengths in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, path, generator, networkx

I have a long list of sources and targets that form a graph as follows:

```
id_a = [...] #source nodes
id_b = [...] #target nodes
distance = [..] #distance between source and target nodes

G = nx.Graph()
path, length = [], []
for a, b, c in zip(id_a, id_b, distance):
    G.add_edge(a, b, weight=c)
```

cl is a subset of all the nodes in the graph and I want to extract the paths interconnecting all of cl together so I use all_simple_paths()

```
path = []
for i in range(len(cl)):
    for j in range(len(cl)):
        if i != j:
            path.append(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=cl[i], target=cl[j]))
```

I want to be able to list all the simple paths and their lengths so I try:

```
for i in range(len(path)):
    total_length = 0
    for j in range(len(path[i])-1):
        source, target = path[i][j], path[i][j+1]
        edge = G[source][target]
        length = edge['weight']
        total_length += length
    length.append(total_length)
```

But I keep getting the error

```
object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

And I can't figure out how to convert the generator of all_simple_paths() to lists that I can iterate over and extract the full lengths of all the paths.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation of [all_simple_paths](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html), you will see that it returns a generator. So, just use `extend` instead of `append` method like this

```
path = []
for i in range(len(cl)):
    for j in range(len(cl)):
        if i != j:
            path.extend(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=cl[i], target=cl[j]))
```

For more info on why `extend` works in this case, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/8160718).

Also I see in the last part of your code, you are setting `length` as `length = edge['weight']`, then appending using `length.append(total_length)`. This will return as error, since the edge weight will be an `int`. Use different variable names something like this

```
path_weight = []    #<----- List to store all path's weights
for i in range(len(path)):
    total_length = 0
    for j in range(len(path[i])-1):
        source, target = path[i][j], path[i][j+1]
        edge = G[source][target]
        length = edge['weight']          #<--- Get the weight
        total_length += length
    path_weight.append(total_length)     #Append to the list
```